# Database help trying to get Functions from a group through users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I need to check whether a USER is a part of a group which has functions which give them access to a usermanagement page.. what i current have is

```
def user_managment
      # If they are in group 1              AND user has function id 1 (user management)
      if current_user.group_ids.include?(1) && current_user.function_ids.include?(1)#&& group.function_ids.include?(1)
      flash[:error] = "You have access to user management!"
      else
        flash[:error] = "You have DO NOT access to user management!"
      end

      if current_user.group_ids.include?(1) && group_ids(1).function_ids.include?(1)
        flash[:error] = "Test"
      end
    end
```

im unsure how do check if they have the string user management in the table from the userscontrollers can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're talking about here is access control, please please **please PLEASE**, stop what you're doing and look at [one of the many, excellent authorization/ACL gems out there](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization.html).  For example, using [acl9](https://github.com/be9/acl9) you could have some code that's much more comprehensible and expressive, such as:

```
access_control do
  allow :manager, :of => User, :to => :user_management
end
```

Rolling this stuff yourself is a bad move, and you'll end up with a lot of messy code intertwined through your app, very hard to maintain, and impossible to ensure it's always doing what you need it to.